TypeError: 0, _$$_REQUIRE(_dependencyMap[15], "redux").isAction is not a function (it is undefined)
Everything works when you remove the persisted reducer, and does not work with the persisted reducer. This is likely due to an issue with redux-persist, which is an older but still extremely popular library, that has not been maintained, and it will be difficult to find the solution.
I have also now edited the file down to be the most simplified way to reproduce the issue, but at its core it's the same issue I mentioned in the original post - a redux-persisted reducer.
Note, I've deleted several things that are included in the default setup:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#use-with-redux-persist
To reduce complexity of the example. I can give my full store.js file if desired, but people seemed to feel it was overcomplicated for troubleshooting.
"@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.6",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.10",
"redux": "^4.2.1",
"redux-api-middleware": "^3.2.0",
"redux-mock-store": "^1.5.4",
"redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
"redux-persist-expire": "^1.1.0",
"redux-persist-transform-immutable": "^5.0.0",
"redux-saga": "^1.3.0",

And the store:
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import {
  persistStore,
  persistReducer,
} from 'redux-persist';
import rootReducer from 'reducers/rootReducer';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
};

const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);

export const makeStore = () => {
  const store = configureStore({
    reducer: persistedReducer,
  });

  return store;
};

export const store = makeStore();

export const persistor = persistStore(store);

So if I change this line:
reducer: persistedReducer,

To this line:
reducer: rootReducer,

And remove this line:
export const persistor = persistStore(store);

Everything works
But for whatever reason my resulting reducer always comes out undefined with redux persist. Without redux persist, no such issue happens.

The error doesn't appear to be coming from your code. Could just be a corrupt installation. Try rm -rf node_modules && npm install

No, I've tried that a few times, and just tried it again now. I think it's some rare combination of factors, but haven't been able to figure it out yet despite digging into the code and trying a bunch of things, was throwing this out into the ether to see if anyone else had had the same issue ever

You have a tonne of stuff going on in your store file... try applying some basic debugging steps like commenting out all the extra "stuffs" and use a plain basic Redux store, and incrementally add a reducer/middleware/etc one at-a-time until it breaks. This should at least help narrow your focus to a specific unit of code.

@DrewReese Yeah, I've tried all that. I only posted this after extensive, extensive debugging for about 12+ hours.
It works when you remove the persisted reducer and use a non-persisted reducer, as I point out above

Not sure why the node_modules refresh is being updated - that is NOT THE ISSUE. I have done it. Extensively, at least 5-10 times in various configurations

It was due to the most recent version of Redux, which adds isAction for typing. Updating from 4.2.1 to 5.0.1 fixed the issue (I typically avoid updating to major revision updates for a few iterations to prevent potential compatibility issues and early adopter bugs)
